# Twitter Bootstrap: Center Text on Progress Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, centering

I've been using Twitter's bootstrap and I would like the text on the progress bar to be centered on the on bar regardless of value.

The below link is what I have now.  I would like all text to be aligned with the bottom most bar.

Screenshot:

[image: progress bar]

I've tried my best with pure CSS and I'm trying to avoid using JS if possible but I'm willing to accept it if it's the cleanest way to do it.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 86%">517/600</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 200, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5:** (Same as v4x)

```
<div class="progress position-relative">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <small class="justify-content-center d-flex position-absolute w-100">60% complete</small>
</div>
```

---

**Bootstrap 4 with utility classes:** (Thanks to *MaPePeR* for the addition)

```
<div class="progress position-relative">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <small class="justify-content-center d-flex position-absolute w-100">60% complete</small>
</div>
```

---

**Bootstrap 3:**

Bootstrap now supports text within a span element in the Progress bar. HTML as provided in Bootstrap's example. (Notice the class `sr-only`is removed)

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span>60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

... It does however only center the text according to the bar itself, so we need a little bit of custom CSS.

Paste this in another stylesheet/below where you load bootstrap's css:

CSS:

```
/**
 * Progress bars with centered text
 */

.progress {
    position: relative;
}

.progress span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
 }
```

**JsBin file:** http://jsbin.com/IBOwEPog/1/edit

---

**Bootstrap 2:**

Paste this in another stylesheet/below where you load Bootstrap's CSS:

```
/**
 * Progress bars with centered text
 */
.progress {
    position: relative;
}

.progress .bar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.progress span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    color: black; /* Change according to needs */
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then add text to a progress bar by adding a `span` element outside `.bar`:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 50%"></div>
    <span>Add your text here</span>
</div>
```

**JsBin:** http://jsbin.com/apufux/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for the details. Small correction. Even for bootstrap 3 you should have ".progress { position: relative; }". Without this if your progress bar is in a div it won't respect the width of the div. (1) [without progress position relative jsbin](http://jsbin.com/umIkAge/2/edit) (2) [with progress position relative jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifInIZic/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks, Amir. I'll add that to the explanation.

Comment: Example for bootstrap 2 only worked when i put the span before the div[class=bar]. The span was otherwise pushed to the right according to the percentage filled.

Comment: And solution for text color http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820200/is-it-possible-to-change-text-color-based-on-background-color-using-css

Comment: I think there's a "left: 0" missing in the ".progress span" selector. Also remove the "//" comment as it's not CSS compliant.

Comment: This is an oldie, but with Bootstrap 2, for span instead of setting the width to 100% I set z-index to 2, left to 0, and right to 0.

Comment: @Driice Both `width: 100%` or `left: 0; right: 0;` should work. Your solution works due to `position: absolute;`, but I find the 100% width to be clearer.

Comment: I've just tried this with bootstrap 4.5 and I find I need to ad mt-2 to <small> class attribute, otherwise the text isn't centered.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3 answer, as shown in bootstrap example

```
<div class="progress text-center">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    <span>60% Complete</span>
  </div>
    <span>40% Left</span>
</div>
```