# How can I keep the progress bar number value centered and on top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of progress bars displaying different values in real time. My only problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to keep the number value in the center of the bar, as well as on top at all times. Right now it's being pushed 'ahead' of the blue bar, and disappears when it goes outside the right side of the bar.

Here's how it looks:
[image]

Markup:

```
<td class="gridTableCell">
    <div style='position: relative' class='progress progress-info'>
        <div class='bar' id='signalRdepthRangePercentage-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #' style='width: #: DepthRangePercentage#%'>
        </div>
        <span class='gridSpan' id='signalRdepth-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #'>#: ViewUnitContract.CurrentRun.LatestWellLogEntry.Depth#</span>
        <span class='hidden' id='signalRMaxDepthRange-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #'>#: MaxDepthRange#</span>
        <span class='hidden' id='signalRMinDepthRange-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #'>#: MinDepthRange#</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

And my css 'gridSpan':

```
.gridSpan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #676767;
    width: 100%
}
```

The first of the three spans is the one that displays the number value inside the bar.
Any suggestions how I can keep this centered at all times, and not pushed in front of the blue filler with a huge margin?

Comment: Can we have a fiddle with the whole CSS/HTML for the progress bar?

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: Combination of Twitter Bootstrap, Kendo UI and SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I finally figured this out based on this fiddle:
http://jsbin.com/apufux/2/edit (Wonder why I've never seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937470/twitter-bootstrap-center-text-on-progress-bar?rq=1) before!?)

Seems that I was missing some style overrides to the .bar and .progress part:

```
   .progress {
        position: relative;
    }

    .bar {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .progress span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
        text-align: center;
        color: #676767;
        width: 100%
    }
```

Anyways, thanks for your effort! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do something like the following:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5VBGr/1/)**

The outer element has text-align:center

The gridSpan element has display:inline-block (not absolutely positioned)

The inner element (with the blue % progress) needs to be absolutely positioned, so as not to be effected by the text-align:center.

### Markup:

```
<div class="outer">
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="gridSpan">9048.343</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer
{
    width: 70%;
    margin:20px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
    background: aqua;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30px;
}
.gridSpan {
     display:inline-block;
     margin-top: 5px;
     color: #676767;
     position: relative;
     z-index:2;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you knew the width of the value you could do this by adding `display:block;left:0;right:0` and `margin:0 auto` to your class:

```
.gridSpan {
 display:block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 0px;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 z-index: 2;
 color: #676767;
 width: x px; /*(width of value)*/
}
```

Comment: The text seems to disappear behind the content when you increase the percentage over 50.