# How to center align bootstrap progressbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to center the text inside a progressbar using twitter-bootstrap framework v3.0.0.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326764/2154101), but I'm afraid not working on the new version of the framework.

So I tried this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    <span>HELLO</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
  </div> 
  <span>HELLO</span>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HuFw4/

As you can see it centers the text in the filled part or in the empty part, but not respect all the content.

Do you have any idea, or advice advice to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply `position: absolute;` for your span element

[try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HuFw4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%; text-align:center">
    HELLO
  </div>
</div>
```

The text should be centered by style="text-align:center"