# Difficult Web Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to create a CSS or JS Animation for a website. But I don´t know how I can code this. The Animation is difficult to explain, thats why I create a little gif-animation for a better understanding.

http://abload.de/img/animationxep49.gif

//Edit: My main problem is the transition from white to black which I illustrate in the example. Does anybody know a solution for this?

And here is my code without animations:

```js
/* Responsive Navigation */ 
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#toggle').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('nav ul').slideToggle();
        });
      });
   $(window).on('resize', function () {  
      if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 860px)').matches) {
              $('nav ul').show();
     }
     else {
        $('nav ul').hide();
    }
 });
```

```css
/* Allgemeines */

html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    color: #0a0a0a;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-size: 7.14rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
a {
    transition: 0.3s;
}
a:hover {
    color: #717171;
}
a:active {
    font-weight: 700;
}






/* Spezifisch */

.logo {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0a0a0a;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 1,57rem;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
.logo a:hover {
    color: #717171;
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;

    padding-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #0a0a0a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    clear: both;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;


}
header h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.darken {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1);
}


/* Breakpoints */

@media screen and (max-width: 860px){
    .logo {

       width: 100%;
       padding: 6px 0 7px 0px;
    }
    .logotext {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    #toggle {
        display: inline;
        float: right;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    nav ul{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        display: block;       
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 84px;
        font-size: 6rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 830px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 70px;
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 56px;
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Von der Berkelaue</title>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic|Playfair+Display' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="logotext"> Von der Berkelaue</a> 
        <a href="#" id="toggle"> Menü</a> 
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aktuelles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Über Uns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Würfe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gästebuch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <header style="background: url(img/header.jpg) no-repeat 25% 30%;-moz-background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; ">
       <div class="darken">
            <h1>Willkommen bei <br /> den Berkelauern!</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <content>

            <h1>Willkommen bei <br /> den Berkelauern!</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae repellat soluta veritatis architecto, cum quod adipisci excepturi at aperiam iste!</p>

    </content>

    <script src="js/functions.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//Edit Nr.2:

Now I have a solution which works on a example page. Now I have to try that this works on my page.

```css
.first, .second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 40%;
  
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
  }

.second {
  color:black;
  max-height:60px;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="first">It´s a test.<br />But it won´t work on my site.</h1>
<h1 class="second">It´s a test.<br />But it won´t work on my site.</h1>
```

Does anybody have a good idea how I can create a animation which works?

Thanks, Jannis

Comment: Is it on click, or triggered by any event, or it should happen as you slide down?

Comment: It should animate when you scroll down. This ist a good example: http://scrollmagic.io/ 

But my main problem is that I don´t know how to change the color from white to black like I show in the example.

Comment: That will be a little harder. One possible way is to have 2 divs with the text, scrolling down. One is behind the image, the other is inside the image div. The inside one will disappear (like display: none) as it scrolls past the visible parent (image), and the other will simply appear because it was just behind the image.

Comment: Thanks Ted, this is a good idea!
I edit my first post and did try this solution. It works great with non-responsive websites. Now I have to look how I can make it work in a responsive website.

Comment: See [Invert CSS font-color depending on background-color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve the effect you are aiming for using just:

1. 3 `CSS3 Transitions`; and
2. A few lines of `javascript` (to control when the transitions activate)

See example below:

```js
function startAnimation() {
var frame = document.getElementsByClassName('frame')[0];
var image = frame.getElementsByClassName('image')[0];
var paragraph = image.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

var newParagraph = paragraph.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(newParagraph);
frame.insertBefore(newParagraph,image);

setTimeout(function(){
image.classList.add('animated');
paragraph.classList.add('animated');

setTimeout(function(){
newParagraph.classList.add('animated');
},2400);


},1000);

}

window.addEventListener('load',startAnimation,false);
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
}

.frame {
position: relative;
width: 700px;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.image {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 700px;
height: 364px;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/hdCeKIz.gif');
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.frame p {
position: absolute;
top: 94px;
width: 700px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
color: rgb(0,0,0);
transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.image p {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.image.animated {
transform: translate(0,-365px);
}

.frame p.animated {
transform: translate(0,-125px);
}

.image p.animated {
transform: translate(0,365px);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
<div class="image">
<p>Willkommen bei<br />den Berkelauern!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And easy way to make animation in the browser is using a javascript library
check this
https://greensock.com/ and here some examples https://greensock.com/examples-showcases https://greensock.com/beziertweens i use it in my projects when i need complex animations that i can't solve using only css

Example

```
            // asuming your text have a top 200px
            TweenMax.to($('text'),2,{
                top:"600px" //it will move your text to 600px in 2 seconds
            });
```

Comment: The library is great. But the moving text isn´t my main problem. I don´t know how to change the color from white to black with the animation I showed in the example.

Comment: This is easy with  css , check this tutorial [the tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)