# Which css property is it?

Tags: css, colors, css-filters, mix-blend-mode

The property, I think, makes for example dark text color on light background if it is set to be light and text cannot be read...or reverses text color if it is on image and/or vice versa.

I've seen some questions on SO with it but really can't find them anymore and dont remember property name. In case I am unclear:

[image: Python]

If text color would be set to white, we couldnt read it because python logo has some white space around it and text is over image. There is a css property which would set text to black as it is now. What is its name?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe you talk about `mix-blend-mode: difference`?

Comment: No its not text-shadow

Comment: maybe mix-blend-mode: difference?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `filter` property is what you're looking for :

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: invert(1) saturate(0);
    filter: invert(1) saturate(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/agSSc.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you I also i will check filter `:)`