# Change colour of fixed text based on underlaying colours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed menu that scrolls on top of both light and dark backgrounds.

If the text is white it becomes invisible when on top of white elements. I would like to find a way where the color of the text changes dynamically as I scroll on the page.

My menu:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper footer-wrapper">
<nav>
    <div class="column">
    <a href="#" class="prev-section">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column links">
    <a href="#" class="next-section">Next</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

A working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ua06Lbwk/5/

Any ideas?

Comment: can you give us an example fiddle / snippet ?

Comment: You may want to check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color

Comment: Without canvas magic, your best bet is to just add stroke to text. Actually @Michael's suggestion sounds good. Never seen that before

Comment: @kukkuz Added a JSFiddle

Comment: @Michael as you can see in my JSFiddle I'm afraid that it won't work as the content of my site is dynamic.

Comment: @ÅsmundSollihøgda for the fiddle you have given, I have a solution using jquery by checking the scroll position... looks like for your dynamic site it would not be enough? want we to post that?

Comment: @kukkuz no unfortunately. The text will be on top of fx slideshows with both light and dark images, and it would be great to have it change dynamically due to the background colours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to add/remove a css class depending on the height of the divs.

Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    link
    </nav>

    <div id="element1">
    </div>

    <div id="element2">
    </div>

    <div id="element3">
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 }

#element1 {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

#element2 {
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: white;
}

#element3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.active {
  color:black;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var element1height = $( "#element1" ).height(); 
   var element2height = $( "#element2" ).height();
   var total = element1height + element2height;
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if( st > element1height ) {
   $("nav").addClass("active"); 
   } 
   else {
   $("nav").removeClass("active"); 
   }
   if( st > total ) {
   $("nav").removeClass("active"); 
   } 
  }); 
 });
```

You can use jQuery to get the height of the divs - if the user scrolls past the height of `<div id="element1">`, it will add a class to `<nav>` which changes the color of the text within. If the user scrolls past the sum of `<div id="element1">` & `<div id="element2">`'s height - it will remove the class.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ua06Lbwk/12/)