# animate inline style back to initial state

Tags: html, angularjs, css, animation, css-animations

I've implemented a CSS solution to animate a style that is set inline with the [guidance from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/). Also used [help from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color/25707161#25707161) to have the text blend with CSS

I have the animation of the label going both ways (on load and reset) but the progress bar itself immediately goes to Zero

The width of the `div` gets set inline like this:

```
<div class="progress-black" ng-style="{width:progress}"></div>
```

And the onload animation is simple

```
.progress-black {
    background: black;
    animation: progress-bar .5s linear;
    z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
   0% { width: 0; }
}
```

[Here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webedge/rsu5e44c/)

It seems like `@keyframe` animations need a 100% value, which is set dynamically, so not sure how to express that in CSS.

My particular app has the ability for a user to click 'reset'. Is there a way to have the animation happen back to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few problems in your code and there is two solutions for you:

**first solution:** - and the better one

1. in your case there is no need to use animation, its enough if you will use `transition: width 2s;` - and you should do that.
2. you checking if the value "exist" with `if (scope.value)` and when you reset the width of the progress remain as it was and not changed
3. you adding `.zero` class that color

[see here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsu5e44c/16/)

**second solution:**

1.. in your case there is no need to use animation, its enough if you will use `transition: width 2s;` - and you should do that.

2.. if you have `zero` class set `.progress-black { width: 0 !important; }` so the width will be 0 (important because you want it to be stronger then the inline css).

[see here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsu5e44c/15/)

Comment: Thanks for the help!