# Javascript text color changing depend on background

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have an audio player with a 00:00 navigation pattern situated above the music album cover.

[image: navigation numbers]

My question is how to make these navigation numbers white when the album cover is black and black, while the cover is white.
How can I make such a thing on vanilla javascript? Should it be a function to analyze an image's pixel color?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color

Comment: Thx, but this link is not exactly what I am looking for - my background, not a color, but a picture, so the problem is - color-switching depending on background picture color.

Comment: Since it sounds as though you might be getting dark background, or light or a mixture would it be better, to ensure the user can always see the numbers, to just give them a black background and have them white regardless of what they are on top of?

Comment: @A Haworth yes, but unfortunately, I need all navigation tools above the album cover, so these numbers must switch their colors.

Comment: You can give a fixed background color just to the numbers (not the background cover).