# Set text color to white on red background and black text color on white background with CSS

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color

I need a *CSS* styling that makes the text color white when the background is red and a black text color when the background is white.

My red background has the following color: **#d6002e**

I added this *CSS* to my text:

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
color: #29FBFF;  // Inverted color of my red
```

Now  it looks like this :

[image]

My text gets the inverted color of the background, which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invert CSS font-color depending on background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color)

Answer (score -2):

I feel this should solve the problem

```
.my-red-bg {
    background: #d6002e;
    color: white
  }


.my-black-bg {
    background: black;
    color: white
 }
```