# Switch between two color based on background contrast using HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

[image]

I am trying to implement a range display, like in the image and the main challenge I am facing is to dynamically switch the font color of value when its background is darker.

I have already tried `mix-blend-mode: difference;`, but it doesn't help.

I want the font color to switch only between the two colors displayed in the image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981820/10749726 . is this useful?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could hard code the font color to change when the progress bar is more than 0%

Comment: Nah, hardcoded won't be right. for example on 10%, only half of the number would be covered with a darker background. That's why I was looking for a solution based on CSS.

Comment: Where would the number be located for 10%? Half inside the bar as you said? Or you could push the number to the side until it's a larger amount. Otherwise, you could make the number font half-transparent. I personally would do that.

Comment: @Ahmad MRF's comment worked for me.. it is resolved!