# jquery addClass to element if css has style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

please have a look at following question and answer, the seccond answer (with the many upvotes) 
[Jquery: How to check if the element has certain css class/style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759631/jquery-how-to-check-if-the-element-has-certain-css-class-style)

looks like this:

```
if ($('#yourElement').css('position') == 'absolute') {
    // true
}
```

so this is awesome but I would like something like

```
if ($('#yourElement').css('position') == 'absolute') {
    $(this).addClass('xxx');
}
```

so the element with the ID "yourElement" gets a class added

what is the easyest way to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
$('#yourElement').addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
    return $(this).css('position') == 'absolute' ? 'xxx' : '';
});
```

For more information on the syntax take a look at the [API for `.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: this one I like the most, thank you, and thanks to all the others

Answer (score 2):

Assign `$('#yourElement')` to a variable. Then perform the check on that variable and add the class to it as well. This simply saves on the number of queries made to the DOM with the `$()` function in your example and in the likely possibility that further manipulation is required.

For example:

```
var your_element = $('#yourElement');
if (your_element.css('position') == 'absolute') { your_element.addClass('xxx'); }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourElement = $('#yourElement');    
if (yourElement.css('position') == 'absolute') {
        yourElement.addClass('xxx');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Cache your element first
var $element = $('#yourElement');

if ($element.css('position') == 'absolute') {
    $element.addClass('xxx');
}
```