# if an element has a certain CSS value do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

When my button is clicked I change the color of the text,
 after this copy changes text I would like to preform another action.

I wrote the following, but am not able to get a console or alert to work:
**http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/IltKJ**

```
$('#my_button').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

    $(this).css('background', '#666666');
    $('#my_button').css('color', '#f58733');

    if ($('#my_button').css('color') == '#f58733') {
        alert('my_button has the color orange');
    }

});
```

I tried the CSS I found from [Tamas's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759631/jquery-how-to-check-if-the-element-has-certain-css-class-style).

Any thoughts on why the alert doesn't get hit?

Comment: Some browsers (firefox in particular I think) use `rbg(x,x,x)` for colors rather then `#xxxxxx`. This might be the problem you're facing.

Comment: @Bucky24, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Try using classes instead of setting the color property directly

Comment: A better option is to add a class instead. Then you can use `.hasClass('abc')`.

Comment: why are you using `$(this)` in one place and `$("#my_button")` in another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

<kbd>[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/omlGq)</kbd>

```
$('#my_button').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    if ($('#my_button').is('.clicked')) { //or use $('#my_button').hasClass('clicked')
        alert('my_button has the color orange');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! :D I had a problem with loading a page after clicking that button. Well the page would load, but the color wouldn't change, I'd have to click it again to get the color to change. So I figured the page loading interrupted the color change

Answer (score 1):

I update your code....tested in Chrome:

```
$('#my_button').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

 $(this).css('background', '#666666');
 $('#my_button').css('color', '#f58733');

 var color = $('#my_button').css('color');
 alert(color);

 if(color == 'rgb(245, 135, 51)'){
 alert('Hi');
 }

});
```

Check Here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dilux