# Animate element with specific class and CSS properties

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I read [Jquery: How to check if the element has certain css class/style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759631/jquery-how-to-check-if-the-element-has-certain-css-class-style) and have got this working -

```
if ($(".box").css('display') == 'block')
{
  
    console.log("message  2 - Div with box class exists and css Block exists")


}
```

I read [how to create jquery slide left and right toggle](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-create-jquery-slide-left-and-right-toggle-effect.php) and got this working -

```
 $(".box").animate({width: "toggle"});
```

I can't seem to combine the two above together though. These two attempts failed -

```
   // ($(".box").css('display') == 'block').animate({width: "toggle"});
   // ($(".box").css('display') == 'block').animate({width: "toggle"});


   var datebox = ($(".box").css('display') == 'block')
   datebox.animate({width: "toggle"})
   datebox.animate({width: "toggle"})
```

**Update 1**

I tried Cucunber's suggestion and got this error -
`Uncaught TypeError: ".box".each` is not a function

[image]

**Update 2**

I solved the problem highlighted in Update 1 by adding `$` to `('.box')`, Cucunber updated his answer below based on the issue I faced.

**Update 3**

I tinkered with Cucunber's solution and eventually solved my problem with this code.

```
$(".box" ).each(function( index ) {


   if ($(this).css('display') == 'block' ) { 



console.log( index + ": " + $( this ) );
  



   }
})
```

Comment: Please state your end goal.  Should this happen on click of a button or when the page loads?   1) you have 2x toggle - if you toggle something twice it goes back to where it was, so nothing "appears" to have happened  2) you've converted an `if (expression)` to just `(expression)` (without the `if`)  3) *always* debug your variables a simple `console.log(datebox)` would show you that **you have a boolean**, so `true.animate..` makes no sense - **always check the console for errors** (which you'll have this this code)

Comment: `if ($(".box").css('display') == 'block') $(".box").animate({width: "toggle"});`

Comment: Rather than use `.css("display") == "block"`, use `$(".box").is(":visible")` as "block" won't include eg `inline` or `inline-block` (or any other "visible" display property)

Comment: When the calender widget appears I want to apply an animation. I am using infinite scrolling datapicker (https://github.com/systemantics/infinite-scrolling-datepicker/blob/master/demo.html) so unfortunately the instructions from jqueryui (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#animation) don't help.

Comment: I have multiple date input fields on a page. I am checking for css('display')=='block' because I only want to apply the animation to the visible calendar.

Comment: "*I am trying to find a way of selecting elements which have a specific class*" - then use a class selector:  `$(".myclass")`

Comment: "specific class and CSS style"

Comment: Can you get the class selector to also look for elements which have specific CSS properties?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence `'$('.box').css('display') == 'block'` returns boolean statement. If you know, `.animate` method should be used with the html element (selector). Try to use something like this:

```
'$('.box').css('display') == 'block' && $('.box').animate({width: 'toggle'})
```

combine it with `'.each()'` and the final result will be:

```
$('.box').each(function(){ $(this).css('display') == 'block' && $(this).animate({width: 'toggle'}) })
```

Comment: I am trying to find a way of selecting elements which have a specific class and CSS style.

Comment: add some changes

Comment: I am getting this error message - Uncaught TypeError: ".box".each is not a function

Comment: I have amended my original question

Comment: add $ to ('.box')