# How to get one that is not hidden tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have three similar div tags as shown below:

```
<div data-test="someId" style="position: fixed; visibility: hidden;">more tags</div>
<div data-test="someId" style="position: fixed; visibility: hidden;">more tags</div>
<div data-test="someId" style="position: fixed;">more tags</div>
```

Note: here data-test id is same for all three.

All I want is the tag that is not hidden i.e third one

I've tried `cy.get('[data-test=someId]').should('not.have.css', 'visibility')` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:visible` jQuery selector. Beware of which route you go with cypress retryability.

```js
// get only visible element(s)
cy.get('.element:visible')
  // retry cy.get('.element:visible')
  .should('be.visible')

// get element(s)
cy.get('.element')
  // filter only visible element(s)
  .filter(':visible')
  // retry .filter(':visible')
  .should('be.visible')
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I was using ```cy.get('.element :visible')```. I was using space that was causing some trouble. But now it's good

Answer (score 0):

I see that it's tagged with jQuery so here is one way you can do it:

[Jquery: How to check if the element has certain css class/style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759631/jquery-how-to-check-if-the-element-has-certain-css-class-style)